# TypeError: slider.children.first is not a function

Tags: jquery, slider, jscript, bxslider

i am working on http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker slider

my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
       minSlides: 4,
       maxSlides: 4,
       slideWidth: 170,
       slideMargin: 10,
       ticker: true,
       speed: 90000
    });
});
```

see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z32Q3/1/

my problem is how to stop sliding on mouseover

Comment: Add `slideWidth` to `50` and `slideMargin` to `10` to slow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code:

```
tickerHover:true,
useCSS:false,
```

**tickerHover** Ticker will pause when mouse hovers over slider.

> Note: this functionality does NOT work if using CSS transitions!

```
default: false
options: boolean (true / false)
```

You can check more option here: [bxslider-4](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4).

Comment: @user3016108 I have updated the answer. you need to add the  `useCSS:false,` also. and this will work.